# Write multiple labels from sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, label

I have 2 labels that need to be given value from sql server db

so

```
sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=2"
sqldr = sqlcmd.executereader
while sqldr.read
   label1.text = sqldr(0)
   label2.text = sqldr(0)
end while
```

now how do i put two different values in these two labels??

Comment: Where are you getting the second value from?

Comment: well its 2 values from database, 2 rows one after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim index as integer

while sqldr.read
   Select case index
      Case 0
        label1.text = sqldr(0)
      Case 1
        label2.text = sqldr(0)
   End Select
   index += 1
end while
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting (at most) one row with one field (assuming `id` is PK). Since you don't want the same value in both labels, I suspect what you actually need looks more like this:

```
sql = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id IN (2, 3)"
sqldr = sqlcmd.executereader

sqldr.read
label1.text = sqldr(0)
sqldr.read
label2.text = sqldr(0)
```

Error handling is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

(Revised answer)
Try:

sqldr = sqlcmd.executereader

label1.text = sqldr.Item(0)

sqldr = sqlcmd.executereader

label2.text = sqldr.Item(0)

Comment: i cant select 2 values. i dont think u understand the question. Its 2 rows coming from table. So one after another it needs to fill labels

Comment: @user970225 Two rows are **not** coming from the table. Only one row, `WHERE id=2` is coming from the table.